# go http 1.22 subrouter

Tags: go, httprouter

So I want to get rid of one more dependency (gorilla/mux) and use the std `http.ServeMux` with it's new [routing patterns](https://go.dev/blog/routing-enhancements).

The problem is, that gorilla/mux had this concept of a subrouter, which could handle everything under a specified path.

I needed to serve paths like:

```
GET /api/user/id
POST /api/user/id
GET /api/product/id
```

So I had something like:

```golang
apirouter := mainRouter.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
users.RegisterHandler(apirouter)
products.RegisterHandler(apirouter)
```

and then in eg. `users` package:

```golang
func RegisterHandler(router *mux.Router) {
    subrouter := router.PathPrefix("/user").Subrouter()
    subrouter.HandleFunc("/{id}", getUser).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    subrouter.HandleFunc("/{id}", postUser).Methods(http.MethodPost)
    subrouter.HandleFunc("/{id}", updateUser).Methods(http.MethodPut)
}
```

How could this be achieved with `http.ServeMux`? I want to be able to create a subrouter, pass it around and register new routes under it.

Something like this?

```golang
func RegisterHandler(router *http.ServeMux) {
    subrouter := http.NewServeMux()
    router.Handle("/user", someMagicMiddleware(subrouter))
    subrouter.HandleFunc("GET /{id}", getUser)
    subrouter.HandleFunc("POST /{id}", postUser)
    subrouter.HandleFunc("PUT /{id}", updateUser)
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `router.HandleFunc("GET /api/user/{id}/", getUser)`? and similarly for the product as well i.e. `router.HandleFunc("GET /api/product/{id}/", getProduct)`

Comment: that's a possibility, but it's "clearer" for me to define all of the paths inside of a package that handles it and the package doesn't need to know its prefix for it.

Comment: IMHO, the first seems much cleaner, rather than obscuring it with a sub-router, but i don't think a sub-router concept exists in 1.22. I don't think the release has 1-1 mapping with every single third party router feature in it

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I think I have it:

```golang
package httphelp

func Subrouter(router *http.ServeMux, route string) *http.ServeMux {
    sr := http.NewServeMux()
    route = strings.TrimSuffix(route, "/")
    router.Handle(route, removePrefix(sr, route))
    router.Handle(route+"/", removePrefix(sr, route))
    return sr
}

func removePrefix(h http.Handler, prefix string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        path := r.URL.Path
        r.URL.Path = "/" + strings.TrimPrefix(strings.TrimPrefix(path, prefix), "/")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        r.URL.Path = path
    })
}
```

It creates a new `http.ServeMux` which handles all subsequent requests under that prefix. And the sub-paths can be registered independently :)

```golang
apirouter := httphelp.Subrouter(mainRouter, "/api")
users.RegisterHandler(apirouter)
products.RegisterHandler(apirouter)
```

`users` package:

```golang
func RegisterHandler(router *http.ServeMux) {
    subrouter := httphelp.Subrouter(router, "/user")
    subrouter.HandleFunc("GET /{id}", getUser)
    subrouter.HandleFunc("POST /{id}", postUser)
    subrouter.HandleFunc("PUT /{id}", updateUser)
}
```

Any enhancements welcome :)

Comment: Just note that this way you have several routing lookups per incoming call, not just one. If performance is the ultimate goal then it would be counter-productive.

Comment: I may be missing something subtle, but it seems you are reinventing [http.StripPrefix](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#StripPrefix).

Comment: Downvoted because, as Peter mentions, `http.StripPrefix()` does exactly what you're trying to do with this code (but battle tested and hardened by real life use).

Comment: @JoryGeerts you're right. Also if you have a pattern in the previous router you can't get it in here for some reason. It's easier to just pass around the prefix, concat it and do the sub-routing that way.